# My code is throwing an exception when I try to find a document that does not exist

Tags: java, mongodb

My code throws this exception: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

It throws it when I enter a username or a password that mongodb can't find in the database, I tried to debug it in many ways but I can't find the statement that is throwing the exception.

The thing is that I want to display a message to the user when the username or password doesn't match in the database

```
public class GetEmployee {

MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create();
MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("MirandasShoes");
MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("Employees");

public Employee getEmployee(String username, String password) {
    FindIterable<Document> findIterable = collection.find(new Document("Username", username).append("Password", password));
    MongoCursor<Document> cursor = findIterable.iterator();
    Employee e = new Employee();
    if (cursor.hasNext()) {
        Document doc = cursor.next();
        //ArrayList<Object> o = new ArrayList<>(doc.values());
        e.setId(doc.get("_id").toString());
        e.setName(doc.get("Name").toString());
        e.setAddress(doc.get("Address").toString());
        e.setEmail(doc.get("Email").toString());
        e.setPhone(doc.get("Phone").toString());
        e.setUsername(doc.get("Username").toString());
        e.setPassword(doc.get("Password").toString());
    }
    return e;//Get the shoes
}
```

}

Comment: in which line u have NPE?

Comment: the first line says this: at UI.Login.btnLoginActionPerformed(Login.java:99) But it refers to the file where I am calling the method

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your `collection.find()` call is returning null so when you call `MongoCursor<Document> cursor = findIterable.iterator();`, findIterable is actually null and wouldn't have the iterator() method.

Try checking `if (findIterable)` right after your `collection.find()` line of code.

Comment: I added the if statement and checked if it is not null but it still throws the exception

Comment: You say "checked if it is not null"... do you mean your code was `if (findIterable !== null) {}` or did you do `if (findIterable) {}`?

Comment: I did `if(findIterable != null)` because when I do `if(findIterable)` it says that it cannot be converted to boolean

Comment: Sorry, I missed the 'java' tag and was thinking 'javascript' which is the driver I'm more familiar with and not the java one.  I still suspect that the find method is the root of the problem, perhaps it has something to do with the query?  I stumbled across this page: http://zetcode.com/java/mongodb/.  About half-way down, there is some examples about forming the query parameter for the find method.  Maybe that will guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score -2):

if(findIterable.iterator() != null )

try this!!

Comment: please keep null check on iterator